# Move splitters in design mode

Tags: qt, user-interface

When i add splitters, it acts as a layout, but also allows to resize the widgets *in runtime*. So, for example, i managed to lay out my widgets in this way:

[image]

Therefore, i can resize my widgets in runtime. As i noticed, this function is also available in designer mode, but it doesn't work properly. I tried to hover over my splitter and drag it in designer mode, but it only replaces the entire widget.

[image]

That is how does my main window look like in QtDesigner. I haven't tried to code yet. The problem is, that even though i used to set a stretch factor, my widegt's look in designer mode and in runtime completely differ. **They have another sizes**.

So, what are the problems:

- **Firstly**, i can't change my widgets sizes properly, using stretch factors. I don't know, i tried to change size policies, but i did't manage to see an effect. I have somehow changed size of the vertically oriented widgets, but when speak about horizontal orientation - stretch factor and size policy doesn't change anything at all.
- **Secondly**, i can't move my splitter in designer mode. It's position is constant, by default, it's always somewhere in the middle.
- **Thirdly**, i have bugs (i think so) with my widget sizes in designer mode. They differ with widget's sizes in runtime.

**Question:**
So, how can i change widget's sizes properly? Maybe there's a way of **moving a splitter in designer mode** - do newer versions of Qt have it? Currently i'm using Qt 5.9.9.  Also, why these bugs, and are they bugs at all. Maybe i just should update my Qt to newer versions to get access to newer functionalities?

*Comment:* I'm not sure if stretch factors work with layout as they do with widgets. I'm using layouts exactly the same way i use widgets. My layout's wrong(maybe) use may have caused this problem. Anyways, i'm entirely new to Qt, and may not know something to understand it completely.

Comment: Qt layouts take a bit of getting used to, but they work really well when you get them set up properly. As a general guideline, try to avoid explicitly setting widget sizes; instead, set `sizeHint` and `sizePolicy` and let the layout engine do the rest of the work. As far as I know, you can't resize a splitter in design view; use `setSizes()` at runtime to do this (https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsplitter.html#setSizes). You can however preview the form by pressing Alt + Shift + R.

Comment: Yeah, i know about preview. But that's weird that i can't set splitters position inside QtDesigner, even though it has such a fucntion (it doesn't work...). I also try to understand size policies, and how they are used. Maybe i can somehow change widget's size in designer? I really need it, 'cause application i'm developing is bigger than this example, and changing sizes manually is a big mess, then i should already have layout when i reach "code point". Maybe i somehow can "treat layouts like widgets"?